# Why does mesh.rotation.set work but mesh.rotation.copy doesn't?

Tags: three.js

If I do:

```
mesh.position.copy(p);
mesh.rotation.copy(r);
```

The position will update but rotation won't. If I do:

```
mesh.rotation.set(r.x, r.y, r.z);
```

instead, it works. (p and r are THREE.Vector3 objects of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Object3D.rotation.copy()` takes a `THREE.Euler` as an argument, not a `THREE.Vector3`.

Have a look at the source code so you can see what it does.

three.js r.70

Comment: Oh crap, all this time I didn't realize Object3D.rotation was a Euler not a Vector3. Thanks.